# statusCode:401,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized

Tags: android, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm having trouble with Paypal SDK when I use direct credit card.

```
[request failure with http statusCode:401,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:{"name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","message":"Unauthorized payment","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","debug_id":"1d9b150a66aa1"}
E/paypal.sdk: UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the error?

Comment: 401

Unauthorized

The request lacked proper authorization. Used in conjunction with the WWW-Authenticate and Authorization headers. here it is i dont know also where i can upgrade to pro my paypal account. 2 days searching how and i cant see it